# How does blood flow to and from the brain when a choke is applied to one side of the neck

Tags: human-anatomy, blood-circulation

In the sport of Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu and Submission wrestling there are some chokes that only target one side of the neck, meaning only one of the carotid arteries. In the context of blood flow, how is this possible since we have two carotid arteries located on the "right" and "left" side of the neck?

A friend of mine gave an explanation that the neck, head and chest can be seen as a circular flow of blood and if one where to stop the flow in the left or right part of the neck than that would stop the "circular flow". Is this correct?

Here is a video showing an arm in guillotine which I believe (and the author states) only target one of the carotid arteries: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYEMu_8pX8k)

To concisely summarize the question: How does a single sided neck choke work in the context of blood flow?